# How to call a server side function from javascript code using "tag functions">

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax

For starters, ive searched what is the "tag operator" <%=%> to no answer, so i'll be referencing to it as that

i'm implementing a [progress bar](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1047/jQuery-tooltip-animated-progress-bar) in ASP.NET and C#, this is the relevant part of the user control:

```
<div class="progress_container" >
    <div class="progress_bar tip" id="ProgressBar" title="78%"></div>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript">        
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("ProgressBar").setAttribute("title", '<%=getPercent()%>')
        var percent = $('.progress_bar').attr('title');
        $('.progress_bar').animate({ width: percent }, 1000);
    }
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnProgressBar" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Go!"  id="btnProgressBar" OnClientClick="myFunction()" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this is the function from code-behind:

```
public string getPercent()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
    return randomNumber + "%";
}
```

witch manages to work quite nicely for JUST one time, then nothing, its like the call to the function `'<%=getPercent()%>'` just works one time. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Either you can use inline properties like this</strike>

```
var randNum= '<%= Percent %>';

public string Percent
{
    get
    {
         return getPercent();
    }
}
```

or you can use some thing like this.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "RandValue", "var randNum= '" + getPercent()+ "';", true);
```

Where randNum is the javascript variable which you would want to access on client side

**UPDATE**

What you need to do is call setTimeout in javascript and call this function after some interval

You can have a look at this example by [Dino Espito](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708746.aspx) how to build context sensitive progress bar. Although its in MVC, the client side code would be same

**UPDATE 2**

Found this article by again [Dino Espito](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163393.aspx) in which he builds a progress bar(similar to yours) using ASP.NET

Comment: well, for starters my understanding of that tag was flawed, it´s just a sustitutuion, but you made the greatest effort to give a working solution so i think you deserve the accepted anser. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's not exactly the answer on your question but you can do it like this (using properties) for sure

```
public string GetPercent
    {
        get
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
            return randomNumber + "%";
        }
    }
```

and than just call it from the aspx file like so

```
<%= GetPercent %>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question - it's more a case of the OP not realising that the `<%= %>` is only called when rendering on the server, and will not be called again on the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do like that. You'd need to use AJAX/AJAJ to have a progress bar that continually updates.

<%=blah()%> is just a substitution. The first time the page is generated it evaluates it and just replaces that part of the document with the result of the evaluation, so you can put a variable, function, resource, etc there.

It looks like you're using jQuery so take a look at $.ajax()